# how to expand a statement multiple times based on template variable arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I have the following pseudo code:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void f(int index) {
    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> funcs;

    funcs.push_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(type_1).name() << std::endl; });
    funcs.push_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(type_2).name() << std::endl; });
    funcs.push_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(type_3).name() << std::endl; });
    funcs.push_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(type_4).name() << std::endl; });

    funcs[index]();
}
```

Imagine that the `Ts...` parameter pack holds `type_1`, `type_2`, `type_3` and `type_4`.

how can I expand the parameter pack in order to achieve something like this? I mean - how can I get 4 `push_back()` calls if there are 4 parameters in the template pack, and also have the different types in the different lambdas? I don't know the syntax..

And can I actually get some sort of an array of such functions at compile time, so there are no push_backs at runtime?

C++17 solution is ok, but C++14 is best.

Comment: Please clarify?

Comment: Please also show how you want to use this function. Will you call it several times? Just once? Creating and filling a vector just to select a specific index seems very wasteful.

Comment: Yeah, I sorta have to agree with the people above me. This seems like an oversimplification to an XY problem.

Comment: `std::function<void>` is not a type.

Comment: @Yakk thanks - fixed it

Comment: @StoryTeller I have some json and I need to deserialize it into a variant. I have the index of the variant type at runtime, but the corresponding type in the variant has not been constructed yet - so I need to create the type based on the runtime index and deserialize the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update.

From re-reading the question I think you just want to call the function once for the I'th type.

I which case it's trivial at compile time:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
void show_type()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Ts>
void f(int index) {

    using function_type = void(*)();
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Ts);
    constexpr std::array<function_type, size> funcs = 
    {
        &show_type<Ts>...
    };
    funcs[index]();
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
        f<int, double, std::string>(i);
}
```

example output:

```
i
d
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Comment: This might be more helpful if you connected it to iterating over types instead of values.  You could use tags to carry the types and extract them inside?  Or I guess pass `typeid`s?

Comment: is the funcs array guaranteed to be constructed at compile time?

Comment: @onqtam yes. it's constexpr.

Comment: If you manage to get [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/vKCFenU8) to compile with gcc you are golden (currently compiles with MSVC)

Comment: forget about my last comment - it turned out to be a bug in GCC - and in version 8 it will be fixed (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519147))

Comment: and one last thing... again - how do you KNOW the array is initialized at compile time? it compiles fine without ```constexpr```, and just saying it is constexpr doesn't GUARANTEE that it will be executed at compile time, since it's not used in a constexpr context...

Comment: @onqtam constexpr does guarantee compile time initialisation of variables. Not necessarily functions. The compile really does "know" what the variable's value will be, as it can itself be used in a constexpr constant (for example as a template argument).
Whether or not the compiler will choose to make a copy of the constexpr object in order to build the jump table is a QoI issue. clang is better than gcc at this. gcc actually produces the code you might expect if the variable is static const.

Answer (score 3):

For C++17, something like this, I suppose

```
(funcs.push_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl; }), ...);
```

or, better (IMHO), using `emplace_back()`

```
(funcs.emplace_back([](){ std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl; }), ...);
```

But remeber that is

```
std::vector<std::function<void(void)>>
```

not

```
std::vector<std::function<void>>
```

In C++14 (and C++11) you can obtain something similar with the trick of intialization of the unused array; the function can be written as

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void f (int index)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> funcs;

   (void)unused { 0, (funcs.emplace_back([]()
      { std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl; }), 0)... };

   funcs[index]();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void f(int index) {
  int i = 0;
  auto _ = {
    (index == i++ ? ((std::cout << typeid(Ts).name() << std::endl) , 0) : 0) ...
  };
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UDBK49483)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is do something for the `n`th type in a template parameter pack, where `n` is a runtime variable, then the `vector` + `function` approach isn't really great. Better to add an index sequence in there and fold:

```
template <typename T> struct tag_t { using type = T; };
template <typename T> constexpr inline tag_t<T> tag{};

template <class F, size_t... Is, typename... Tags>
void match(F f, size_t i, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tags... tags) {
    auto inner = [&](auto tag) { f(tag); return true; };
    bool matched = ((i == Is && inner(tags)) || ...);
    if (!matched) {
        // failure case?
    }
}

template <typename... Ts, class F>
void match(F f, size_t i) {
    return match(f, i, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), tag<Ts>... );
}

template <typename... Ts>
void foo(int index) {
    match<Ts...>([](auto tag){
        std::cout << typeid(typename decltype(tag)::type).name() << std::endl;
    }, index);
}
```

This construction allows you to add a failure case, where you might call the passed-in function with some special type:

```
struct failure { };

template <class F, size_t... Is, typename... Tags>
void match(F f, size_t i, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tags... tags) {
    auto inner = [&](auto tag) { f(tag); return true; };
    bool matched = ((i == Is && inner(tags)) || ...);
    if (!matched) {
        f(failure{});
    }
}

template <typename... Ts>
void foo(int index) {
    match<Ts...>(overload(
        [](auto tag){
            std::cout << typeid(typename decltype(tag)::type).name() << std::endl;
        },
        [](failure ) { /* ... */ }
    ), index);
}
```