# problems not expanding a parameter pack with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, g++, variadic-templates, c++17

I have the following code which compiles with Visual studio 2017 but doesn't with GCC 7:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void print(int in)    { std::cout <<    "int: " << in << std::endl; }
void print(double in) { std::cout << "double: " << in << std::endl; }

template <typename... Ts>
void print(std::variant<Ts...>& data, int type_idx) {

    using function_type = void (*)(std::variant<Ts...>&);
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Ts);

    constexpr std::array<function_type, size> funcs = {
            [](std::variant<Ts...>& data2) {
                data2 = Ts(); // default construct it so we can get it later
                print(std::get<Ts>(data2));
            }...};

    funcs[type_idx](data, val);
}

int main() {
    print<int, double>(1);
}
```

> error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':

Any ideas how to make it work? The point is to NOT expand the `Ts` pack in the lambda but to use the current type we are expanding for

Comment: Oh cool, apparently gcc 8 fixes this. Awesome.

Comment: @Barry and when is the release date for gcc 8? april 2018? :D and do you think there is a chance of it being released in a patch for 7?

Comment: As yet unannounced. And I don't know.

Comment: it's a g++ bug but... if you want use g++7 you can define a template function (say `template <typename T, typename ... Ts> constexpr void foo (std::variant<Ts...> & data2) { data2 = T(); print(std::get<T>(data2)); }`) and initialize `funcs` as `constexpr std::array<function_type, size> funcs { { &foo<Ts, Ts...>()... } };`

Comment: @max66 give it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: the question is marked as duplicate: I can't write an answer (but don't worry: it's important it's useful)